# MacBook's webcam is not working

Tags: applications, macbook, skype

The webcam is simply not recognized by the OS. The Camera app doesn't recognize it, Skype won't find it etc.

I am using a MacBook Pro 2,2 (it's old) and the Software Center won't find any driver.

Any tip? I have to buy an external one?

Answer (score 1):

You need to install Isight, follow this tutorial.

https://turanct.wordpress.com/2010/06/11/use-your-macs-isight-on-ubuntu/